# Reverting block rewrite, how to set all child block elements

Tags: layout, blocks, magento-1, overrides

I had a custom page where I had to rewrite `page/page.phtml`, and inside the template file I needed some methods. So I had to rewrite the base class `Mage_Page_Block_Html`. 
This is how my module's layout xml look liked:

```
  <vendorpage_index_index>
      <reference name="root">
          <action method="setTemplate">
              <template>page/vendor.phtml</template>
          </action>
      </reference>
  </vendorpage_index_index>
```

and the rewrite in the module's `etc/config.xml`:

```
    <blocks>
        <page>
            <rewrite>
                <html>OurCompany_Vendor_Block_Frontend_Vendor</html>
            </rewrite>
        </page>  
    </blocks>
```

And it worked perfectly. However, Later, I found that it might make a conflict, because it rewrites the block class which is used everywhere, and it might rewrite other modules' rewrites. I removed the above rewrite xml, trying to redefine the block name `root`

```
<vendorpage_index_index>

    <block type="vendor/frontend_vendor" name="root" output="toHtml" 
      template="page/vendor.phtml" />

<vendorpage_index_index>
```

But the problem was, I had to manually add millions of child blocks which were added to the `root` block manually. I suppose this is because of occupying the `root` block with a different `type` making the `root` forget all its children elements.

So I added the millions of blocks which were assigned to the `root` before the handle `root` occupation. Now I have a very long layout file full of duplicates,

```
<vendorpage_index_index>

    <block type="vendor/frontend_vendor" name="root" output="toHtml" 
      template="page/vendor.phtml">

       <millions of blocks ...>

    </block>
<vendorpage_index_index>
```

which Evils of Duplication (®) are chasing. How do I avoid the duplication?

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption isn't right. Rewriting a block with a new type **does not make the original block forget all its children elements**

When you rewrite a block like you did in your `config.xml` everytime the `page/html` block is instantiated, your custom block is instantiated instead.

As long as you make your new custom block extend the original block **you should not have to change the layout declaration for this block**.

Thus you don't have to add the following to your layout:

```
<block type="vendor/frontend_vendor" name="root" output="toHtml" 
  template="page/vendor.phtml" />
```

**Because the root block is natively defined for all pages** in `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml` :

```
<default translate="label" module="page">
    <label>All Pages</label>
    <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml">
    ...
```

Comment: If my assumption is wrong, why wouldn't the `phtml` load its child elements? And manually adding the blocks solved my problem? Look, I extended the type class, it was not just the `phtml`. Many of my rendering logic is embedded in the class found by `type="vendor/frontend_vendor"`

Comment: @shampoo well you should start by checking whether or not the module output is disabled in the backend. Also ensure the module itself is enabled. You can also add `echo get_class($this);` in your template file to ensure that your rewrite works.

Comment: My rewrite *worked*. The problem was that, I was worried if another module rewrote the Block, and my module re rewrote that, it's gonna be a mess. Sorry, I'll edit my question to make that clear.

Comment: @shampoo well that's the problem with rewrites. Any module can rewrite the same block. If you know there's already a rewrite for this block you can either extend the rewritten block or merge the changes from the other rewrite into your rewrite

Comment: Oh, I see. That's a far better solution. However, you know I am not sure of what future developers will do. They might rewrite my rewrite, just like what I did.

Comment: @shampoo well there's no other way unfortunately. Whatever you write, there's always a risk that someone else rewrites it ;)